# FPC Compile as Static Library

Tags: gcc, linker, freepascal

I have the following Pascal code:

```
Library foo;

uses
  ctypes;

procedure Dummy; cdecl;
begin
end;

exports
  Dummy;

begin
end.
```

To compile it to a .o file, I do:

`ppcrossx64.exe -Cn -CcCDECL -O2 -Xs -XS -Xt foo.pas`.

It creates a `foo.o` and a `link.res` file.

Then I do `ar -q foo.a foo.o link.res` to create `foo.a`. However, if I link to the file with GCC (linking with my C++ program), `Dummy` symbol not found.

FPC says that it is link compatible with gcc. Why can't I find the symbols? What am I doing wrong? If I don't specify `-Cn`, it compiles it to a `.dll` which works. However, I need a static library.

**Edit:** It is also generating this batch file:

```
@echo off
SET THEFILE=C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\foo.dll
echo Linking %THEFILE%
ld.exe -b pei-x86-64  --gc-sections  -s --dll  --entry _DLLMainCRTStartup   --base-file base.$$$ -o C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\foo.dll link.res
if errorlevel 1 goto linkend
dlltool.exe -S as.exe -D C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\foo.dll -e exp.$$$ --base-file base.$$$ 
if errorlevel 1 goto linkend
ld.exe -b pei-x86-64  -s --dll  --entry _DLLMainCRTStartup   -o C:\Users\Brandon\Desktop\foo.dll link.res exp.$$$
if errorlevel 1 goto linkend
goto end
:asmend
echo An error occured while assembling %THEFILE%
goto end
:linkend
echo An error occured while linking %THEFILE%
:end
```

Double clicking it creates a `.dll` file that works.

Comment: Use bintools to inspect the library file foo.a and see what it contains. This is how you start debugging such issues. Otherwise you are working blind.

Comment: It contains the .o file and the .res file.

Comment: `0000000000000000 T P$FOO_$$_DUMMY` and a bunch of others.

Comment: Looks like the issue is name mangling.

Comment: Don't use library for static libraries. Just compile an unit.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I tried that. I compiled the unit and then placed it into a `.a` file with `ar -rcs foo.a foo.o` No difference. Still the same `undefined reference to Dummy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a bit, and appparently you need to declare it  [export](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu73.html#x190-21200014.10.3) or us [public name](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu82.html#x199-22100014.10.12) (or public alias if you want both mangled and non mangled symbol)

```
unit xx;
interface

uses
  ctypes;

procedure Dummy; cdecl;export;

implementation
procedure Dummy; cdecl; 

begin
end;


begin
end.
```

Comment: This is much better because the names aren't mangled. However, I just found out I can't build static libraries with FPC or Lazarus ={

Comment: Well, that's very negative,  but it is indeed not a preprepared track, so you probably need to research some things like how to link+integrate RTL, setup the memory manger and hook startup code.

Comment: I tried this: https://github.com/martok/fpc-static-gcc  No cigar. Didn't work too well.